# How to combine file extension using BasicNewFileResourceWizard and initial file context while usingaWizardNewFileCreationPage at once?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a class for giving extension to newly created file.

```java
public class MyNewFileWizard extends BasicNewFileResourceWizard
{
  @Override
  public void addPages()
  {
    super.addPages();
    MyWizardNewFileCreationPage page = (MyWizardNewFileCreationPage )getPage("newFilePage1");
    page.setFileExtension("css");
    addPage(page);
  }

  @Override
  public void init(IWorkbench workbench, IStructuredSelection currentSelection)
  {
    super.init(workbench, currentSelection);
    setNeedsProgressMonitor(true);
  }}
```

Also I have a class to give that created class's context

```java
public class MyWizardNewFileCreationPage extends WizardNewFileCreationPage
{

...

@Override
  protected InputStream getInitialContents()
  {


//to give same strings context for every generated css file
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("SAMPLE_CSS_FILE"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    sb.append("SECTION_1"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    sb.append("SECTION_1_BODY_1"); //$NON-NLS-1$

    return new ByteArrayInputStream(sb.toString().getBytes());
  }
```

plugin.xml

```xml
..
<wizard
        category="ui.category"
        id="ui.wizard.MyNewFileWizard"
        name="Create a new app.test File"
        icon="icons/project.png"
        class="MyNewFileWizard"
        project="false"
        >
        </wizard>
```

My goal is to create a css class with already defined context in it. So somehow combining these two class.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `super.addPages` because that will add the normal `WizardNewFileCreationPage`. You have to add only your own page:

```java
@Override
public void addPages()
{
   MyWizardNewFileCreationPage page = new MyWizardNewFileCreationPage("newFilePage1", getSelection());
   page.setFileExtension("css");
   addPage(page);
}
```

But doing this means that the standard `BasicNewFileResourceWizard.performFinish` won't work so you will have to override that as well:

```java
@Override
public boolean performFinish() {
  MyWizardNewFileCreationPage mainPage = (MyWizardNewFileCreationPage )getPage("newFilePage1");

  IFile file = mainPage.createNewFile();
  if (file == null) {
      return false;
  }

  selectAndReveal(file);

  // Open editor on new file.
  IWorkbenchWindow dw = getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
  try {
      if (dw != null) {
          IWorkbenchPage page = dw.getActivePage();
          if (page != null) {
              IDE.openEditor(page, file, true);
          }
      }
  } catch (final PartInitException e) {
      // Show error
  }

  return true;

}
```

Comment: I have revised the `performFinish` a bit. But your `wizard` in the plugin.xml doesn't have the full name of the class - you must include the full package in the `class` attribute.

Comment: Yes i did that but currently i can see the dialog if i remove "addPages" method and with this way Finish button is not working on the dialog..

Comment: do you think the logic in MyWizardNewFileCreationPage is correct?

Comment: What is `sectionCheckbox` - that doesn't even compile

Comment: edited.. was trying something.. I thought getInitialContents method will generate some strings in the file as default..

Comment: I need some default contents in the created css file that is why i have MyWizardNewFileCreationPage this class to append those strings but it is not working...

Comment: I found a solution ill share it here :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyNewFileWizard extends BasicNewFileResourceWizard
{
  WizardNewFileCreationPage mainPage;

  public static final String WIZARD_ID = "ui.wizard.MyNewFileWizard";

  public MyNewFileWizard()
  {
    super();
  }

  @Override
  public void addPages()
  {

    mainPage = new WizardNewFileCreationPage("New File Page", getSelection())
    {
      @Override
      protected InputStream getInitialContents()
      {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("SAMPLE_README_FILE");
        sb.append("SECTION_1");
        sb.append("SECTION_1_BODY_1");

        return new ByteArrayInputStream(sb.toString().getBytes());
      }
    };

    mainPage.setFileExtension("css");
    addPage(mainPage);
  }
  @Override
  protected void initializeDefaultPageImageDescriptor()
  {
    //setDefaultPageImageDescriptor(imageHelper.getImageDescriptor("icon_48x48.png"));
  }

  @Override
  public void init(IWorkbench workbench, IStructuredSelection currentSelection)
  {
    super.init(workbench, currentSelection);
    setWindowTitle("New Solidity file");
    setNeedsProgressMonitor(true);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean performFinish()
  {
    IFile file = mainPage.createNewFile();
    if (file == null) {
      return false;
    }

    selectAndReveal(file);

    // Open editor on new file.
    IWorkbenchWindow dw = getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    try {
      if (dw != null) {
        IWorkbenchPage page = dw.getActivePage();
        if (page != null) {
          IDE.openEditor(page, file, true);
        }
      }
    }
    catch (PartInitException e) {
      //openError(dw.getShell(), "Problems opening editor", e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```